# pygame for python on virtual (VMWare) Windows XP on Mac OS10.6.8

Tags: python, pygame

I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows XP as a virtual machine on my Macbook (OS 10.6.8) using VMWare.

I'm going through the python/pygame video tutorials at thenewboston.com and am running the following code:

```
bif="bg.jpg"
mif="ball.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import * 

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1196,733),0,32)

background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
           pygame.quit()
           sys.exit()


    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mouse_c.get_width()/2
    y -= mouse_c.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mouse_c, (x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

The program (which displays a background jpg and a ball that follows your mouse cursor) is running as expected bar one problem, which is that the ball doesn't follow the cursor as expected, rather it moves seemingly randomly around the edge of the screen.

Is this because the x,y co-ordinates being returned by the get_pos, get_width, and get_height functions are unexpected data due to the fact that I'm running a virtual machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because you're working on a virtual machine in the general sense. I just tested the code out on a Mac running 10.7 using a Windows 7 virtual machine in Parallels with PyGame + the Enthought Python Distribution.

The code works fine on that system, with my modest little soccer ball following the mouse. It may have something to do with how VMWare feeds the mouse coordinates, but it's not all virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the behaviour on virtual machines so I can't really help you there. But it might help you to say that I did try your code on my Linux machine and the program do work as expected with the image following the mouse.

So, given that, you are probably right that there's something strange happening with the mouse methods when running in the virtual machine.